# can't launch settings in centos 7?

Tags: centos, centos-7

I tried rebooting a couple of times .

it just loads for a couple of seconds and then nothing happens no errors nothing .

while launched from terminal `gnome-control-center` it outputs

`gnome-control-center: error while loading shared libraries: libwbclient.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please can you take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). We need additional information to provide support, such as; What exactly you try to do (run a command or click a button)? What you've tried & tested will also help narrow down the cause for the issues you're experiencing.

Comment: It's freshly installed I was wondering if theres a way to launch it from the terminal maybe it'll dump an err or any useful output !

Comment: From the command line you can launch the settings with `gnome-control-center`, I found this command from a quick Google. If you could launch that from a terminal and then paste the command output into your initial question so we can start building up details regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you experienced states that libwbclient is not locatable, usually this means that it is not installed, try installing it with the following (as root):

```
yum install libwbclient
```

Should you see the message `Package libwbclient already installed and latest version`. Then you may need to reinstall it with:

```
yum reinstall libwbclient
```

Comment: Package libwbclient-4.4.4-9.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Comment: Which user are you running the gnome command as (root or your own user)?

Comment: Tried it with my user as well as the root

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional step to try, could you give that a go and then let me know if it works.